# SQL Injection - is it possible when the variable is processed using intval()?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I have very short question, but no one asked it yet. Is it posible to do SQL injection in such piece of code?:

```
$number = intval($_GET["number"];
mysqli_query($link, "Select Username FROM Users WHERE USER_ID = $number");
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: you should start using mysqli or PDO instead, as of PHP 5.3 the mysql extension is deprecated.

Comment: Mysql is just for example, I'm already using mysqli!

Comment: Sorry :) You have to take into account that a lot of people do not know, and it seems hard to root out the usage as it is. That is why a lot of users point this out on every occasion, to help prevent new php users reading outdated code when they first start out.

Comment: I edited my post to match your criteria :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because intval will always just be a number. The same goes for (int).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to using `intval()`no, so you are fine.

But: `mysql_query()` is deprecated (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Consider using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: Yes, I now that. Already using mysqli, just for example... Thank you. 
I was thinking abou older PHP, where $_GET["name"] was the same thing as $name. So, when the intval failed, it could be not assigned and there fore that would be possible.